# error after adding arm64 support

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, arm64

I added arm64 support in my build settings, and when run my project i get an error in my curlrules.h file. The error:    '**curl_rule_01**' declared as an array with a negative size. 
Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
typedef char
 __curl_rule_01__
[CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)]; //where the error occurs
```

Comment: What cocos2d version? If it's any version prior to v2.2 you *have* to upgrade to v2.2 or later. All previous versions are not compatible with 64-bit arm64 code.

Comment: Ok, but how do I upgrade cocos2d?

Comment: Check the forums. Essentially: remove/delete old cocos2d folder, move new one in place, remove any red cocos files from xcode project and add any cocos files that aren't already added, update your code to match API changes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a step by step guide to upgrading to cocos2D 2.2 and 64-bit because it didn't seem as straightforward as it should.

http://ralabaloza.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/updating-cocos2d-iphone-application-to.html

Hope it helps.